# Passport photo editor (to take passport photo by myself)

Tags: photography, iphone-app, travel

Can someone recommend a passport photo editor for me? I'd like to take passport photo by myself. I've tried some apps but none of them can change background.

Comment: Why do you want to change the background? Does it need to be a particular color or pattern? How about taking the picture with a flat wall behind?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use a second app like background eraser?

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/background-eraser-superimpose-photo-editor-cut-out/id815072622?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

If you are in the United States and use a web browser that still supports Adobe Flash, the US Dept of State Affairs has a **[Photo Tool](https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/passports/content-page-resources/FIG_cropper.swf)** you can use to crop your picture. It's also a good idea to review [passport photo requirements](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/requirements/photos.html) before submission.

Take a picture in front of a plain, white wall. If shadows are a problem, step away from the wall or modify the light source.

**Editing** the background of **passport photos is likely to be frowned upon** by the government agencies involved. Auto levels and white balance should be okay. More than that is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 0):

The best passport photo editor app I'm using is called **Photid**, it can not only change the background color ,but also crop the photo into a required size ,it has all kinds of passport photo size of 69 countries ,no need to check it out by yourself anymore!

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photid-passport-photo-editor/id1325926562?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

If you need a photo for your passport (or any other official document), you can take it yourself with a smartphone at https://passport-photo.online/. All you have to do use your phone and go the website, then take a picture. The rest will do software - it will change the background and frame the faces in the right way. The only key is to choose the right type of document and country.

It's very usefull and intuitive photo editor but you have to pay for photo 4$ - then you can upload the photo and you get a guarantee that it will meets the requirements.

Before you take a photo, you can also read the requirements for photo supplies for a each document https://passport-photo.online/requirements

Answer (score -1):

You can [create passport photos](https://makepassportphoto.com), and match the required background automatically using [makepasportphoto.com](https://makepassportphoto.com/en/p/photo-for-united-states-passport?plan=ai_automatic). We have a free DIY option and a paid option, where you can digitally download or print your passport photos online.

PS: I am the creator of MakePassportPhoto.com

Comment: Please disclose any affiliation you have with that site.  Thank you.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket sorry about the initial post. Was mind drunk I guess. Have updated my affiliation.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  Much appreciated!  We all make mistakes, and you did a great job rectifying yours.  Thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

Go to an wall with solid colour and take a photo with an smartphone.

After that, use Jotun colour design and the rest is easy.

Simply look at the tutorials and fill the background with white paint.